# Given two real sequences that go to infinity, is it possible to select two subsequences that grow at the same rate asympotically?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Given two positive real sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ that both diverge to infinity, is it possible to choose two subsequences $a_{s_n}$ and $b_{t_n}$ such that $a_{s_n}/b_{t_n}\rightarrow1$?

Comment: You should specify that limits are infinite **of the same sign,** otherwise the conjecture is obviously nonsensical.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not necessarily.  If
$$a_n=2^{2n}\quad\hbox{and}\quad b_n=2^{2n+1}$$
then any $a_{s_n}$ and any $b_{t_n}$ have a ratio of at least $2$ or at most $\frac12$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing how s_n and t_n may be chosen; wouldn't s_n = n and t_n = n - 1 give you two subsequences with term ratios of *exactly* 1?

Comment: @chepner the second sequence is 2^((2n)+1), not 2^(2(n+1)). So the two sequences do not have any elements in common.

Comment: Oh, right. Never mind.